# Set log4j file path param in execution time

Tags: spring, log4j

In Spring I have slf4j with log4j to resolve logging.

I put relative path in log4j.xml configuration, but when i execute app in Netbeans Tomcat and independent Apache Tomcat, relative path is different, and I must change manually.

My idea is obtain context realpath from Spring Controller and set it in log4j configuration in execution time. But I dont know...

How can I change file path param of log4j from Spring Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions for you to try:

Add a [WebAppRootListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/WebAppRootListener.html) to your web.xml - this will configure a system property pointing (default to `webapp.root`, but you can customize using a context-param - see the Javadocs link) to the root of your web application, which you can then use in the log4j.properties/xml file:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.WebAppRootListener<listener-class>
<listener>

<!-- log4.appender.File=${webapp.root}/logs/web-app.log -->
```

Or use the [Log4jConfigListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jConfigListener.html) in your web.xml (which ultimately delegates to a [Log4jConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Log4jConfigurer.html)) - this is similar to the above, but allows you to define a custom log4j configu file and also allows for your web application to monitor the log4j config file for changes made at runtime and automatically update your loggers:

```
<context-param>
    <!-- Configure Log4J from the following config file location -->
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener<listener-class>
<listener>
```

I would also recommend you read the Javadocs for the above in detail - there are some gotchas with regards to deploying multiple webapps in Tomcat and sharing of system properties, but this can all be worked around (providing a custom key for each webapp, rather than the default `${webapp.root}`